# Elixir doctest failed to catch error on struct with enforced keys

Tags: unit-testing, elixir

I have a struct with all enforced key with a doc test like so

```
  @moduledoc """
  Pokemon

  ## Examples
    iex> %Pokemon{name: "Charmander", type: :fire, speed: 20}
    ** (ArgumentError) the following keys must also be given when building struct Pokemon: [:health, :attack]
  """

  @enforce_keys [:name, :type, :health, :attack, :speed]
  defstruct [:name, :type, :health, :attack, :speed]
```

Event though I've specify the resulting error (in doctest) because of pokemon struct don't have some value, the doctest still could not handle it, hence the test failed (doctest).

Comment: I think that's because it's a compilation error, not a runtime error. You can't test it with a doctest. If you really want to, you might need some workaround like use [`Code.eval_quoted`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Code.html#eval_quoted/3).

Comment: I see, but how do you know it's a compilation error in the first place? I have to set up new mix project and run the script so I know it's a compilation error (I'm on livebook when writing that code)

Comment: “how do you know it's a compilation error”—e. g. by the fact it has not been caught by doctest. I actually see an XY Problem here. Doctests are to **demonstrate good scenarios in documentation**, not to be used as unit tests.